# Raphael - Responsive SVG - issues with different browsers

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using RaphaelJS + SVGs but don't get it right with the Responsive Version.

I'm having a picture and an overlay of two SVGs to cover parts of it (on the top and at the bottom). In my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karo/kgQqh/3/ you can see the code
Here the JS:

```
var paperBanner1Bottom = Raphael("banner1_bottom", '100%', '100%');  
 paperBanner1Bottom.path("M0,250V30.07c0,0,260.135,133.59,668.494,150.29c408.351,16.701,660.351,16.701,754.47,16.701c94.121,0,296.577,3.74,377.036,41.689V250H0z").attr({fill:"red", "stroke-width":"0"})
paperBanner1Bottom.setViewBox(0, 0, 1800, 250, true);

var paperBanner1Top = Raphael("banner1_top", '100%', '100%');
paperBanner1Top.path("M0,0v34.96c0,0,182.39,95,480.3,88.16c273.58-6.28,597.33-63.84,775.16-89.68c177.84-25.84,320.7-47.12,545.66,19.76c0-25.84,0-53.2,0-53.2H0z").attr({fill:"red", "stroke-width":"0"});
paperBanner1Top.setViewBox(0, 0, 1800, 140, true);
```

I'm using setviewbox to get the svgs responsive which works out.

The issues in the different browsers: (to see how it looks like in the different browsers see the pictures)
I'm giving the divs (which I'm adding the svg to) the position absolute and put them with either top:0 or bottom:0 on their position

- Firefox works out perfectly!
- Safari is stretching the svg to 100% height of the surrounded div
- Chrome > it's not possible to put the svgs on the top or at the bottom, as they strech out over the whole div and are centered in that.

Did anybody else had problems like that? 
Do you know how to fix that?

Thanks

[image: Image of how its displayed]

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the code of this page: http://www.brichards.co.uk/blog/webkit-svg-height-bug-workaround
I could solve the problem! Yippiiii

See my fixed jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/karo/kgQqh/16/embedded/result/
Probably you could make the code shorter of the function fixWebkitHightBug, but I'm not so good in jquery yet;)

The following Javascript/JQuery code fixes the issue.

```
function fixWebkitHeightBug(){ 
/* Resize campus element */ 
var campusW = 282; 
var campusH = 288; 
var curCampusW = $('#campus').width(); 
var newCampusH = heightInRatio(campusH,campusW,curCampusW); 
$('#campus').height(newCampusH); 
function heightInRatio(oH,oW,nW){ return (oH / oW * nW); }
```

}

```
$(window).resize(function() { fixWebkitHeightBug(); }); 
$(document).ready(function() { fixWebkitHeightBug(); });
```